# Why anybody user the main element

Tags: html

The *main* HTML element is specified in W3C HTML5 documentation, but I never saw any HTML5 website using it.

This tag shouldn't be used ?

Comment: Literally the first result in Google for "html5 main": http://html5doctor.com/the-main-element/

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't explain why anybody use it yet. I know what it is used for, I just don't understand why I never seen HTML5 websites using it.

Answer (score 0):

It is just *very* new and hasn't achieved significant market adoption yet.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is about semantics, and SEO for the future.
 tag should be used for unique content on a certain page, for example if a blind person comes to your website on a text to speech device, main tag will have biggest priority for reading for a blind person.

in that case blind person wont have to read trough everything to get to main content because main stuff if properly mark-aped will be easy to access